# xtext web Load Testing

Tags: eclipse, load-testing, dsl, xtext

Good day...

I have developed a DSL in xtext web using eclipse. It has a login page and multiple users can login from anywhere...

Now my requirement is to test the load of this web DSL.  I need to test:

1. "certain number of users in parallel"
2. how conflicts are avoided/managed"
3. "the perceived latency experienced by the users (the lower the better)"

Please guide me how to perform this load and stress test on Jetty server.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about [xtext-web](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-web) it's just a matter of sending proper [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) simulating your users accessing the endpoint.

Just choose a [load testing tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools) which supports HTTP protocol (the vast majority of them does) and implement your test scenario steps. If you're looking for a Java-based one there are [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) and [Gatling](https://gatling.io/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already tested it with LOAD VIEW. It failed after 41 session with " too many HTTP requests " . After 41 all (around 2500) failed. Please guide.

Comment: There is probably a request rate limiter.

Comment: Where can I set unlimited requests rate? I cannot find request rate limiter anywhere?